# mysterious html flickering on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm trying to use the [Zebra DatePicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/#datepicker-example13) but for some reason when I tap the calendar (doesn't matter which part), that entire section flickers.  If you click on your desktop it doesn't flicker, but strangely enough it flickers on my iPhone.  Looks to be something related to mobile but I'm not really sure what could be causing this.  Has anybody seen this type of flickering before?

I tried asking the original creator but he seems unexperienced in developing for mobile web.

Comment: Why not jQuery UI Datapicker?

Comment: Have you tried it in the Xcode iOS Simulator? If it doesn't happen in that or you're unable to, can you put up a video of it on YouTube?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Instead of offering an alternate plugin can you provide a useful answer? :)  Unfortunately my company has strict requirements for plugins and that is why jQuery's UI was not chosen.

Comment: @Coby Unfortunately I don't have a Mac so I'm unable to run Xcode.

Comment: I suggested it because jQuery UI is fully compatible. I can`t help you, sorry.

Comment: @paulsmith Okay. Setup a camera shooting the iPhone and reproduce the issue. Put up the video on YouTube. :)

Answer (score 1):

The flicker could becaused by the highlighting effect on tap. Since Taps are usually only used on mobile devices this could be it.
Maybe some background element is highlighted on each click.
Try to define this rule for each element to see whether this is the cause of the flicker:

(Css rule)

```
* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
```